# How to find page line position of last paragraph in openXml?( How much space is available in the word document of last page after last paragraph)

Tags: c#, openxml

I just wanted to ask questions to understand how much space is available in the word document last page after last paragraph. If the page is less than half full I will add a table otherwise I will not add (I will use Page Break code then add table). How to find page line position of last paragraph in openXml?

Comment: Is there any resolved code related to this problem to date?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "resolved code"?

Comment: If anyone has solved this problem before, can they write here

Comment: Sure, this is what stackoverflow.com is about. But, as I said in my answer below, there is no solution in Open XML itself. The markup does not represent the information and the code required to provide the information, essentially a layout engine, can‘t be posted here (e.g., size, not open source).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information

Comment: You are welcome. Do you want to accept my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is simple and straightforward. Open XML as such does not provide any solution to your problem.

You would need a layout engine to determine the position of a paragraph on the page and the space left on the page for your table.